# python 3.x - How to fix output alignment

Tags: python-3.x

Long time lurker with a question about lining up code output column in python 3 program. Here's my code for an election program but i'm having trouble getting the output all lined up with each other. was wondering what the deal is. tried using /t but no luck.

```
def getcandidates():
    candidate_number = input("Enter the number of the candidates in the election: ")
    candidate_number = int(candidate_number)
    return candidate_number


def get_votes(num_candidates):
    candidate_names = []
    candidate_votes = []

    space = (20 - len(candidate_names)) * " "
    percent = 10
    print("{0}{1} - {2}%".format(candidate_names, space, percent))

    for candidate in range(0, num_candidates):
        name = input("Enter the name of candidate #{}: ".format(candidate + 1))
        vote = input("Enter the number of votes for candidate {}: ".format(candidate + 1))
        candidate_names.append(name)
        candidate_votes.append(int(vote))
    return candidate_names, candidate_votes


def calculate_results(names, votes):
    print("Election Results")
    print('-' * 45)
    total_votes = sum(votes)
    for candidate in range(0, len(names)):
        if votes[candidate] == max(votes):
            print("{} \t - {:2.1f}% <-- First Place".format(names[candidate], votes[candidate] / total_votes * 100))
        elif votes[candidate] == min(votes):
            print("{} \t - {:2.1f}% <-- Last Place... HAHAHAHA!".format(names[candidate], votes[candidate] / total_votes * 100))
        else:
            print("{} \t - {:2.1f}%".format(names[candidate], votes[candidate] / total_votes * 100))


candidates = getcandidates()

candidate_names, candidate_votes = get_votes(candidates)

calculate_results(candidate_names, candidate_votes)
```

Comment: Please put the actual code that you used in the question instead of a link to a picture... Write your code, select it and use the curly braces above the edit box to indent it.

Comment: Hey man. Please just copy & paste the code, screenshots of code aren't exactly well-received here :D

Comment: fixed code format should display properly on here now.

Answer (score 0):

To get consistent formatting, you will have to truncate the candidate names.

Use e.g. `{:.10s}` as the first item in the format string.

Example in IPython:

```
In [1]: '{:.10s}'.format('this is a test')
Out[1]: 'this is a '
```

Comment: figured it out with spacing had incorrect variable names.